# web3js: what's the difference between web3 and Web3 object?

Tags: web3js

I am new with Ethereum technology. I am studying web3js javascript library from the official documentation(https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3) and i don't understand the difference between web3 and Web3 object. Why can i not use directly web3 for example in this code (in my html file):

```
var web3istance= new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545")); ...
```

Why Web3 if the object is web3? (Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are familiar with object oriented programming, you can think of `Web3` as the class, and `web3` as an instance of the class, i.e. an object. It is also possible to have several different instances of `Web3`:

```
web3_svr1 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(ip_of_server1));
web3_svr2 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(ip_of_server2));
```

You can also see that you can chose an arbitrary name for the instance of `Web3`, it does not have to be `web3`.

Answer (score 1):

When you import web3 in a React project for example, like so:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
```

What you have there is a constructor function and thats why importing it is done with a capital W.

Afterwards, you create a new instance of web3 like so:

`const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);`

So the above code is an instance of web3 and in this case I passed in a few things such as `window` which is a global variable because this example is a case where you may have Metamask which injects web3 onto the global variable and you want to get rid of it for your own copy. `currentProvider` has been configured to connect to the Rinkeby test network and has access to all accounts, public keys and so on.

So I am taking that and giving it to the local instance of `web3`.

Lastly, again if this was a React project, you would export it like so: `export default web3;`